# generate infinite list of RandomGen

Tags: list, haskell, random, infinite

I want to apply a function f which needs a RandomGen over a list. I tried to generate me therefore a infinite list of RandomGen as you can see below. (just random values as generated by the function "randoms" isn't sufficient, because the needed range of the value depends on the input for f.)

```
module Test where
import System.Random (getStdGen, RandomGen, randomR, random)

f :: (RandomGen g, Integral a) => g -> a -> Bool

randomGens :: RandomGen g => g -> [g]
randomGens gen =
  let (i, gen') = (random gen) :: (Int, g1)
  in  gen : (repeatGen gen')
```

Unfortunately the compiler tells me, that it fails

```
Test.hs:13:26:
    Could not deduce (g1 ~ g)
    from the context (RandomGen g)
      bound by the type signature for
             randomGens :: RandomGen g => g -> (g, g)
      at Test.hs:11:14-39
    or from (RandomGen g1)
      bound by an expression type signature: RandomGen g1 => (Int, g1)
      at Test.hs:13:19-55
      `g1' is a rigid type variable bound by
           an expression type signature: RandomGen g1 => (Int, g1)
           at Test.hs:13:19
      `g' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for randomGens :: RandomGen g => g -> (g, g)
          at Test.hs:11:14
    In the first argument of `random', namely `gen'
    In the expression: random gen :: RandomGen g => (Int, g)
    In a pattern binding:
      (i, gen') = random gen :: RandomGen g => (Int, g)
```

Just skipping in the let-binding the type annotation (Int, g1) doesn't work. He needs to have the result-type for the application of "random"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Quick answer

You can define the function you want as

```
randomGens :: (RandomGen g) => g -> [g]
randomGens g = let (g0,g1) = split g in g0 : randomGens g1
```

#### Slightly longer answer

The above probably isn't the best way to go about applying a function that requires randomness to a list. I might define a helper function to do that

```
mapRandom :: (RandomGen g) => (g -> a -> b) -> g -> [a] -> (g, [b])
mapRandom _ g []     = (g, [])
mapRandom f g (a:as) = let (_,g1) = next g
                        in f g a : mapRandom f g1 as
```

You can then write

```
>> g <- newStdGen
>> mapRandom f g [1..5]
([False,False,True,False,True], 1839473859 293842934)
```

#### Best answer

The function `mapRandom` looks very messy. That's because we have to mess around with the fiddly details of manually updating the generator. Fortunately, you don't have to do that! The package `Control.Monad.Random` gives you nice combinators to almost completely abstract away the idea of generators. Say you currently have

```
f :: (RandomGen g) => g -> Int -> Bool
f g n = let (x,_) = random g in x < n
```

I would rewrite that to be

```
f :: (RandomGen g) => Int -> Rand g Bool
f n = do
  x <- getRandom
  return (x < n)
```

and just use `mapM` to map this function over lists. You can run it with

```
>> gen <- newStdGen
>> runRand (mapM f [1..10]) gen
([False,True,True,False,True], 1838593757 1838473759)
```

where the first element of the pair is the result of mapping your random function over the list, and the last element is the current value of the generator. Notice that when defining `f` you don't have to worry about the generator at all - Haskell takes care of updating the generator and generating new random numbers behind the scenes.

Answer (score 4):

Disregarding for a while whether generating an infinite list of random generators is really the way to go, there exists a function called [`split`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-1.0.1.1/docs/System-Random.html#v%3asplit) in `System.Random` that can be used to create a new generator instead of calling `random` on a dummy type and throwing the generated value away. Using `split` you can implement `randomGens` like this:

```
import Data.List (unfoldr)
import System.Random

randomGens :: RandomGen g => g -> [g]
randomGens = unfoldr (Just . split)
```

However, you should probably just use [`randomRs`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-1.0.1.1/docs/System-Random.html#v%3arandomRs) which generates an infinite stream of values in the given range.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem here - compiler can't understand the equality `g1` and `g` (list are always homomorphic!)

It is need to use `ScopedTypeVariables` extension, like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

randomGens :: forall g. RandomGen g => g -> [g]
randomGens gen =
  let (i, gen') = (random gen) :: RandomGen g => (Int, g)
  in  gen : (randomGens gen')
```

We add `forall g` to point on scope context of `g`.

As Chris Taylor mention, this function isn't effective, it is need to calculate random number twice - first time to calculate new `g` and second time to calculate new random number.

So, much nicer to use `MonadRand` saving new generator numbers in the state.

**UPDATED**

For simple cases we could use `zipWith`

```
randomsMap :: (RandomGen g, Random a) => g -> (a -> b -> c) -> [b] -> [c]
randomsMap g f xs = zipWith f (randoms g) xs
```

Comment: Nice information! :-)

In fact I didn't understand what the compiler problem was. Put that together with Chris Taylor's answer and you have got the perfect answer to my problem. :-)